Ubuntu synaptics package libglib2.0-dev doesn't create the file /usr/share/gir-1.0/Glib-2.0-gir
I installed libglib2.0-dev and it does not create a .gir file or a vapi for valac

deb packages are built for specific releases, and as we don't know yours we can't know what's in your package anyway as you've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details. Further you've only provided a statement, with no question actually asked.

libglib2.0-dev doesn't install either a .gir file or a vapi, so you'ere OK with that, however maybe you intended "does not create a .gir file or a vapi for valac" to mean something else.

Since you did not specify your Ubuntu version, I checked with apt-file to see which package owns this file on both Ubuntu 22.04 and Ubuntu 24.04. Both came up with the same result: libgirepository1.0-dev
$ apt-file search /usr/share/gir-1.0/GLib-2.0.gir
libgirepository1.0-dev: /usr/share/gir-1.0/GLib-2.0.gir

Now, I did search for the file exactly as posted above, but I can only assume that the lower-case "l" was a typo.
As an FYI, as @guiverc pointed out, it's vitally important to tag your post with the version of Ubuntu.
